# Benefit to referencing Firestore as a single instance?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a benefit to referencing Firestore as a single instance:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()

db.collection("abc").doSomething...
db.collection("xyz").doSomething...
db.collection("lmn").doSomething...
```

versus:

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("abc").doSomething...
Firestore.firestore().collection("xyz").doSomething...
Firestore.firestore().collection("lmn").doSomething...
```

when referencing it multiple times within the same object or method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second call type saves a lookup of the database object in the app. The performance difference is going to be incredibly minimal though, so I'd recommend picking a better reason to prefer one of the other. For example, I like that `db` is shorter than `Firestore.firestore()`, so that usually my reason for using this form.

Comment: "shorter" is never a good reason in programming. It's either simpler, or easier to read, or removing duplicate code.